# passing boto3 client in multiprocessing library python

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3

I want to run a sub-process where it checks if service in AWS is stable or not.

I have a code like this:

```
import boto3
from botocore.config import Config
from multiprocessing import Process
...
ecs_client = boto3.client('ecs', config=my_config)

p = Process(target=wait_for_ready, args=(ecs_client))
p.start()
...
def wait_for_ready(ecs_client):
   response=ecs_client.get_waiter('service_stable')
...
```

While running the code, I am getting the error as:

```
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'botocore.client.ECS'>: attribute lookup ECS on botocore.client failed
```

I am not sure how can I pass ecs_client to that subprocess here. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Where do you run this code? Sadly your question is not clear and lacks details.

Comment: I run this on my local terminal.

Comment: @Marcin I have tried to make the question more clear as well.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass objects that are not picklable between processes.

So you would either create the client in every process, or create a separate process with the client that would handle requests to SDK via messages from other processes (e.g. with a Queue or a Pipe).